# pointer to function as static member in structure

Tags: c++

```
struct X {
   int f(int);
   static int f(long);
};

int (X::*p1)(int) = &X::f; // OK
int (*p2)(int) = &X::f; // error: mismatch
int (*p3)(long) = &X::f; // OK
int (X::*p4)(long) = &X::f; // error: mismatch
int (X::*p5)(int) = &(X::f); // error: wrong syntax for pointer to member
int (*p6)(long) = &(X::f); // OK
```

I think that p1 and p5 is the same case. Why is p5 wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The C++ Standard's definition of the built-in `operator &` states that only when the parameter to `&` is a *qualified-id*, meaning something like `Class::Member`, does `&` result in a pointer-to-member.  The parentheses make it no longer a *qualified-id*, so it attempts to parse `X::f` directly, which is illegal in this context: you're assigning an `int (*)(long)` to an `int (X::*)(int)`.

The distinction between the two cases resolves an ambiguity.  Let's say that you have:

```
struct X {
    int m;
};
struct Y {
    int m;
};
struct Z : X, Y {
    void F();
};

void Z::F() {
    int X::*p1 = &X::m;
    int *p2 = &(X::m);
}
```

Here, `&X::m` is a pointer-to-member, whereas `&(X::m)` is an ordinary pointer to `int`, using the `X::` qualification to resolve the ambiguity between `X`'s `m` and `Y`'s `m`.

Answer (score 5):

Because the standard says so. From the N3936:

> 5.3.1 Unary operators
>
> 4. **A pointer to member is only formed when an explicit & is used and its  operand is a qualified-id not enclosed in parentheses**. [ Note:
>      that is, the expression &(qualified-id), where the qualified-id is
>      enclosed in parentheses, does not form an expression of type “pointer
>      to member.” Neither does qualified-id, because there is no implicit
>      conversion from a qualified-id for a non-static member function to the
>      type “pointer to member function” as there is from an lvalue of
>      function type to the type “pointer to function” (4.3). Nor is
>      &unqualified-id a pointer to member, even within the scope of the
>      unqualified-id’s class. — end note ]